# no hardware listed in sound settings, but audio works, failed after selecting a different output. 13.04

Tags: 13.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control

The audio was working fine, all hardware listed, but I made the mistake of selecting a different output. The audio stopped working, for a while, I reinstalled pulseaudio and managed to get sound back. However, no hardware is listed in the sound settings, either input or output... all greyed out!

Is there a way to RESET the sound settings? Is there a config file perhaps?

```
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF114 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 5102
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at f6080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

I seem to have to do a fresh install every few months, getting a real pain, any ideas on how to fix this would be good :-) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to delete the .pulse file in the home folder, reboot and this resets the sound settings... Worked for me